# php preg_replace ignore $n in content

Tags: php, preg-replace

My current regex is `/[$]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\,:]*)[$]/` and this will allow me to replace strings like the following for our CMS:

```
$ContentArea1$
$blog:PostTitle$
```

However when we have content which has prices in dollars `preg_replace` gets rid of the first part of the price e.g. `$15 $1 $2 etc`

How can I make `preg_replace` ignore prices within the content?

```
    <?

    $message = 'Below is an example for the content replacement<br/><br/><br/>$ContentArea1$';

    $newMessage = '<h2>Website Coming soon</h2>
<p>
    Are new website will be online soon.</p>
<p>
    Price: $2.50</p>
<h2>
    Twitter Feed</h2>
';





    echo preg_replace('/[$]ContentArea1[$]/',$newMessage,$message);

?>
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest redesigning your data format so that replacement points can be unambiguously distinguished from actual data instead of trying to apply "That looks like a price" heuristics.

Comment: surely if using preg_replace on content that has $2.99 or other prices alike it will replace the beginning whether I use $settings or $blog for our replacement variables as the regex targets just those strings.

Comment: which part are you trying to replace? before or after the `:` ?

Comment: Hi Brian. Currently I am able to replace the the above. The issue is when I have a block of text e.g. "Welcome to $settings:CompanyName$, our services start from $100.00 a month." The start of the price (before the .) gets replace with empty string when using preg_replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your regular expression to include `$` followed by numbers so that the `$` in price values are non-terminating:

```
/[$]((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\,:]*)(?:[$]\d)?)+[$]/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand your problem right but I have three possible solutions:

1. Change the regex, so that it matches only variables that don't start with numbers:

   `[$]([a-zA-Z_\-\,:][a-zA-Z0-9_\-\,:]*)[$]`
2. Change it to match only variables that contain a colon:

   `[$]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\,]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\,]*)[$]`
3. You could also use the function `preg_replace_callback` or the `/e` modifier to call a custom PHP function that only replaces valid variables names.

Comment: I have extended the question above. Hope this makes more sense of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I think your problem is still a bit obscure. I think it would really help if you could post a simple code snippet that demonstrates your problem? Because your regex works fine for me with the given sample text, so I can't even reproduce your problem.

Comment: A very basic example as to what is going on but it does demonstrate the issue better. You should be able to copy the script above and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to allow $1.99 to be displayed in the content that is replacing $ContentArea1$ or any other variable I have using the following function.

```
function preg_replacement_quote($str) {
    return preg_replace('/(\$|\\\\)(?=\d)/', '\\\\\1', $str);
}

$input = '$5 dollars';
$replacement = '$10+$5';
var_dump(preg_replace('|^(.*) dollars$|', preg_replacement_quote($replacement) . ' dollars', $input));
//  output: string(14) "$10+$5 dollars"
```

This now allows me to display $ symbols in the content which is what was required.

Source: http://www.procata.com/blog/archives/2005/11/13/two-preg_replace-escaping-gotchas/

Thanks for all of your answers and comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the basic example of your problem, now it's clear what your problem was :)

Another simple solution would be to use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`:

```
str_replace('$ContentArea1$', $newMessage, $message);
```